# Looping inside switch case to minimize code?

Tags: jquery, loops, switch-statement

I want to know if it is possible to minimize this code by making a function, a loop or any other trick to avoid a block of code 26 lines.

```
$("#inputText").bind('keyup',function(objEvent){
switch(objEvent.keyCode)
{
case 65: $("div:contains('A')").attr("class", styledClass); break;
case 66: $("div:contains('B')").attr("class", styledClass); break;
...
case 90: $("div:contains('Z')").attr("class", styledClass);
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.fromCharCode`:

```
$("#inputText").bind('keyup',function(objEvent){
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(objEvent.keyCode);
    $("div:contains('" + letter + "')").attr("class", styledClass);
})
```

Comment: Awesome! It works, thanks. Also I forgot to put "styledClass" between quotes.

Comment: Great! Please set answer as correct, clicking on the gray V sign near the answer